# Creating an instance from a Java Type

Tags: generics, java-5

I was wondering if its possible to create an instance from a Java Type and populate a parameterised list?

I've got a Type `UserDefinedType` with a member variable `List<AnotherUserDefinedType> list` (as well as some primitive types)

Using reflection (to process custom annotations) on `UserDefinedType` I am processing only member variables with a specific annotation. If a particular property is set on the annotation it means that it is `AnotherUserDefinedType` as opposed to a primitive type so it is handled differently. In this case I was to do exactly what I did with `UserDefinedType`.

The caveat is I have to create an instance of `AnotherUserDefinedType` from `Field.getGenericType()`, and somehow add them to a parameterised type of `List<AnotherUserDefinedType>` and call `UserDefinedType.setAnotherUserDefinedType(List<AnotherUserDefinedType> list)`.

I've tried to find some information on it, but am at a loss now. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter type isn't itself a type parameter, and is a class with a default no-argument constructor, you can do something like this:

```
public class UserDefinedType {
    private List<AnotherUserDefinedType> data;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UserDefinedType inst = new UserDefinedType();
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) UserDefinedType.class.getDeclaredField("data").getGenericType();
        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();  //this is of type "AnotherUserDefinedType"
    }
}
```

It's pretty gross though, and in this case doesn't accomplish anything you couldn't do without reflection (by instantiating `AnotherUserDefinedType` directly).  Maybe you can expand on what your core goal is through all this?  Perhaps there's a cleaner approach that we could suggest.

If the list is itself parameterized with a class type parameter:

```
 public class UserDefinedType<T> {
     private List<T> data;
     //...
 }
```

then this is impossible.   The type will not be available at runtime due to type erasure.

So basically it's only possible when the type is statically known, and if the type is statically known you probably don't need reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. Ultimately It's an implementation of a DAO to deal with a less than common datasource/response. Basically I'm using annotations to marshall data from a a multidimensional array of strings to our domain model without all the boilerplate. The field annotation defines a property in the response that maps to the type. This has the potential to be a user defined type whos values are inside the multidimensional array of strings so I recursively drill-down and process the annotations on the user defined type.